# Does Google have an api to get company info?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

When we search some company in Google, there is a card display the company info in the right area. Does an api exists to get these info? I scan quickly in Google API Console and didn't found it. Does anyone can make sure that is it exists or not?

[image: Search Apple in Google]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Google calls it the knowledge graph. There is [an API to it](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/).